# Are computable functions closed under "less than"?

Tags: computability

Suppose f and g are functions from N to N, f is computable, and f>=g. Is g also computable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: no.

There are uncountably many functions on $N$ that only attain the values $\{0,1\}$, but there are only countably many computable functions.  So, there must be a non-computable function $g(n)$ such that $g(n) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $n \in N$.

Take $f(n) = 2$.  The function $f$ is computable, $f \geq g$, but $g$ is not computable.

Comment: For a specific example, let $g(n)$ be the function which returns $0$ if $n$ encodes a Turing machine that halts (pick any such encoding) and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan neat example!